# Responsive (Design) website does not shrink to fit mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a website: tripavto.com (same issue with trip-avto.ru)

It is supposed to be responsive, however it does not seem to shrink to past 910px to fit the mobile screen.

When i was trying to debugg it in Stylizer, chrome by putting display:none; on each element, nothing has worked. I removed all the elements like that and the website still does not shrink to mobile version.

What am I missing? Why the website is not shrinking even tho it is responsive?

ISSUE: website does not shrink past one point

Thank you in advance, I highly appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: It would've been better if you have posted your code as well.

Comment: The website is based on wordpress so there is no static html file, also there are multiple css files aswell...should i post all the css?

Answer (score 2):

In your css line 49 just find below and comment out as below

```
.container, .navbar-static-top .container, .navbar-fixed-top .container, .navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
/* width: 940px; */
}
```

Comment: This site has two versions of Bootstrap -- which is not good --, the one on line 49 is outside the media queries and is causing the problem. Remove it, clear your cache in both your CMS and in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Required:

```
.container, 
.navbar-static-top .container, 
.navbar-fixed-top .container, 
.navbar-fixed-bottom .container 
{ max-width:90% }
```